# Add effects to already recorded sound with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api, getusermedia

My task is to add some effect to the recorded file.

Here is a script in action I'm using
[Recorder.JS](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html)

and here is a code https://github.com/cwilso/AudioRecorder/blob/master/js/recorderjs/recorder.js

I want to add pitch.

I tried looking in other codes which add some effects to the audio.
But it seems like recorder.js handles buffers differently.

---

edit

```
function playbackRecorderAudio() {
    audioRecorder.getBuffer(function(buffers) {
        var source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = audioContext.createBuffer(1, buffers[0].length, 44100);
        source.buffer.getChannelData(0).set(buffers[0]);
        source.buffer.getChannelData(0).set(buffers[1]);
        source.connect(audioContext.destination);
        source.noteOn(0);
    });
}
```

here is how my code looks now, with this function, I request already recorded audio and play it back.

Can I simulate some effect to get close to this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lr80slqJ3zo
This is in Georgian but I hope you get the idea. Its more like Helium Pitch. (note, I don't whant to change audio speed).

When I tried to research helium effect I found this: http://chemistry.about.com/b/2013/08/26/helium-voice-is-not-higher-in-pitch.htm
it saies that sound should be 2.5 faster then air.

Can I get something close to this?

---

edit

from what @cwilso suggested, http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/granular.html  is the closest I have seen so far. But I could not manage to modify it, to work with my `playbackRecorderAudio()`.
Thats why I'm starting a bounty with everything I have

---

edit

here is a jsFiddle of my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lsvnp/1/

First let me describe what I'm trying to achieve:
I want to record sound from users microphone, add this effect to it.
When user press "stop recording" button (`stopRecording` function) , it will prepend HTML audio which will allow user to listen what he has recorded. If he likes it, he then will upload it to my server (`uploadAudio` function)

WHen page is loaded, recording is not initalized. to initialize recording, user has to press some button which will trigger `recordAudio` function.

Now the problem is that I don't know where to connect my `playbackRecorderAudio` function. to use it as coverter from buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of the granular effect you want is usable. The only thing you need to do is connect the output from your source node to the first node of the granular effects page code. Still that code is a bit messy but I will try to explain it as good as possible beneath.

After some searching in the code, it looks like the audio structure goes like this:

```
source -┬-> grainWindowNode -┬-> panner -┬-> dryGain -> compressor -┬-> destination
        └-> bypass          -┘           └-> wetGain -> convolver  -┘
```

I made the code so it works for you, see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MarijnS95/WK4vt/4/)

This is a bit hard to make as you need to set all the values yourself to fit what you want.

All the code is in the jsfiddle, and there are two things you have to do to make it work:

1. read the comment on top (download that file and put it on the same server as where you     are hosting it, else `CORS` makes sure you can't fetch the resource. (or you must specify a header on the server)
2. Put this code somewhere in your code, so that the function `playbackRecorderAudio()` does something useful. I can help you if you provide me all your code, to make sure it works.

If you want any explainment about the code feel free to ask (I do not know your current knowledge about the audio api, and to explain everything?)

Comment: Hello @MarijnS95, sorry for late answer. I have read your jsFiddle like 100th of times. and this days I was trying to read some documentation, but it's really hard) I updated my question, could you help me a little me bit more? P.S. ilustation helps a lot, I got how this will work, I just don't know where to connect

Comment: Yes, the code does a lot. I don't know how the effects are exactly generated, but I know where the input and output points are. The code is on the [updates jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MarijnS95/WK4vt/5/). On the top there is a comment that explains where to connect (I just added an input and output node to easily connect.

Comment: The fiddle got lost somewhere, so [here is a new one](http://jsfiddle.net/MarijnS95/WK4vt/6/). The input of this is effectsInput and the output effectsOutput.

Comment: The top comment is als gone... To loop your sound through this effect generator you'd best put it inbetween your `audioInput` and `inputPoint`, by changing this line: `audioInput.connect(inputPoint);` to `audioInput.connect(effectsInput);   effectsOutput.connect(inputPoint);`

Comment: I could not manage to apply this but I'm giving up. this is not crucial. anyways I accept your answer since this gives everything one would need with little knolidge of webAudio API

Comment: I don't give up! To help you further: 1. paste my code on the bottom of your code. Run the script and see if any errors occur (might be something to do with variables or syntaxis) try to fix them or else tell them to me, I will help you. Then if that works, do what I said in my above comment: " To loop your sound through this effect generator you'd best put it inbetween your audioInput and inputPoint, by changing this line: audioInput.connect(inputPoint); to audioInput.connect(effectsInput); effectsOutput.connect(inputPoint);" To make it even easier, if you can post all your working code in...

Comment: ... a jsfiddle, so that you have it fully working, then it is a lot easier for me to help you implement the 'messy code' from the granualar effects webpage. so basically copy-paste your html, js and css in jsfiddle. Btw on the side you can import external files, so you might better import the monkeypatch here than to paste it (less messy).

Comment: first of all, thank you.

here is my [http://jsfiddle.net/Ud54b/7/](jsFiddle) . When I place your code and include matrix-reverb4.wav, there is no errors but my browser stacks (chrome) and firefox just restarts.

Comment: I guess this script won't work on jsFiddle because I have included recorder.js Worker from external address. The task is to apply this effects when recording (press RECORD), so I can play it back (maybe save) this later (press STOP & PLAYBACK FUNCTION)

Comment: Have you looked at the console? you are not allowed to load the external file thanks to cors(this is also in my original answer). You need to host it somewhere where cors is allowed, or just scrap that audio part.

Comment: Okay, I see 2 playback options, but the idea was to record the audio with the effect??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45155/discussion-between-marijns95-and-mpa4hu)

Comment: Hello, should I still wait?

Comment: Well, yes. I am very busy with school these days. I also think the implementation of the grainwindow is hard, as that works with a buffer, but I can do that with a scriptprocessor

Comment: take your time then )) I just wanted to be sure

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look at using OfflineAudioContext rather than Recorder.JS - OAC can work in faster-than-realtime.

That said - "helium pitch" looks pretty hard to do, as it alters the harmonics of your voice.  That sounds more like vocoding, with the voice sound being the modulator and the carrier, but shifting the harmonic bands (or something like that).  The YouTube video you pointed to *sounded* like it was actually pitch-shifted, but with rate correction - like granular synthesis.  Check out Chris Rogers' example http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/granular.html - set the speed to 1.0, and the pitch to something greater than zero (several hundred cents, at least).  Is this the effect you're looking for?  If you, you can dig in to Chris' example to see how to do that, or use a live-effect version like the "pitch doubler" in my input effects (http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/input/) (which can actually be set to be faster or slower, and controlled to be something other than octaves).

Comment: Hello @cwilso, glad you answered. I have seen your example, but never had luck to dig into it. in my chrome I have an error (probably because luck of WebGL with my linux drivers) MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS. I tried disabling visualisation, but more I dig, the more errors it had. and my firefox (which can display webGL, it just restarts entire browser (crash).

I liked granular, and will dig into it. its not perfect but close enough I guess. About OfflineAudoContext - I'm not shure about this since I want as wide support as I can get. Recorder.js should be okay with audio less then 5min.

Answer (score 1):

Pitch shifting is achieved using FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) which is implemented in the Web Audio API. O'Reilly has a book "Web Audio API" which covers the API nicely. You can see the chapter on Pitch and the Frequency Domain [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001552/ch04.html).